# rename middle name of multiple files using bash

Tags: bash, rename

I've multiple files located in `/opt/rec/` which I want to rename only some part of it using bash.

Original file name:

```
WK6LZTPR99999999_dig_2017-07-10 01:55:57.xy
```

which I want to change all files with in that directory as:

```
WK6LZTPR99999999_cur_2017-07-10 01:55:57.mp3
```

Comment: @AFSHIN  solution work great really . mmv and rename single line . but it does it work out when I deal with multiple dynamic folders , cause that folder created with random names and how do I change all files with hin those folder when I only know the root folder name which is data with in that folder there are multiple folder where I need to change names of all files with in those folders.

Comment: for file in /opt/data/*/*; do 
    nname="${file%%.*}.mp3"  # strip last part of file till first . seen
    echo mv "$file" "${nname//dig/cur}"  # replace 'dig' with 'cur'
done

error: test.sh: 3: test.sh: Bad substitution
echo mv "$file" "${nname//_xyz/_cur}"  # replace 'dig' with 'cur'

Comment: `for file in /opt/data/*/*; do 
   if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    nname="${file%%.*}.mp3";
    echo mv "$file" "${nname//dig/cur}";
   fi
done`, remember `echo ` is  just used for dry-run, please remove it when you saw rename is satisfied with your expectations

Comment: @AFSHIN  brother for file in /opt/data/*/*; do if [ -f "$file" ]; then nname="${file%%.*}.mp3";  this part work great but the next part  of code echo mv "$file" "${nname//dig/cur}"; fi done  does not work at all its giving red high lighted bar on //xyz/cur  and it does not run , please do check at your end .

Answer (score 4):

Here is `bash` solution.

```
for file in /path/to/*; do 
    nname="${file%%.*}.mp3"  # strip last part of file till first . seen
    echo mv "$file" "${nname//dig/cur}"  # replace 'dig' with 'cur'
done
```

With `mmv`, it's much easier.

```
mmv '*_*_*.*' '#1_cur_#3.mp3'
```

Or with `zmv`:

```
zmv -w '*_*_*.*' '$1_cur_$3.mp3'
```

Comment: 3: test.sh: Bad substitution
after adding actual directory path /opt/rec/*

Comment: Hi, maybe you have directories in that path as well? then you need specify file type as well like `/path/to/*.xy` or add a check file condition `if [ -f "$file" ]; then` or even you can use `find`command's,  please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/385389/edit) in your question and add what did you try and what did you receive in result. thank you

Comment: well you bash script did not work out but mmv '*_*_*.*' '#1_cur_#3.mp3' worked gr8

Comment: bash is also should work. what error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

With *Perl* ***rename*** command:

```
rename 's/_dig_([^.]+)\.xy$/_cur_$1.mp3/' /opt/rec/*.xy
```

Comment: mmv '*_*_*.*' '#1_cur_#3.mp3'   and  
rename 's/_dig_([^.]+)\.xy$/_cur_$1.mp3/' /opt/rec/*.xy

worked gr8

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use 'rename' command in 2 steps:

```
cd /opt/rec/
rename -v "_dig_" "_cur_" *.xy
rename -v ".xy" ".mp3" *.xy
```